# What does ksh %! syntax mean

Tags: shell, ksh

I am tracing a ksh legacy script that is using a "%!tempout" artifact that I cannot decipher.  What does the `%!` syntax mean?  The first usage of it is `touch %!tempout`, so I am guessing it is a filename representation of some kind.  Maybe not specific to ksh?  I tried to echo the statement but it simply gets displayed verbatim.

Other usages of this are:

```
cat %!tempout
mv $!tempout %!tempout2
upr -trans -dp=$duplex -P=$pr %!tempout2
mv %!tempout $1.ps
```

I can't provide more context due to proprietary restrictions.  Hoping this is enough to get some insight.

Comment: What does `set -x` (telling the shell to trace commands as they're actually executed) show it doing? If it shows the name `%!tempout` actually being passed to `cat`/`mv`/etc, there's your answer -- that it *really is* a verbatim name, just an unusual one. OTOH, if a different value is substituted, that demonstrates that there really is something there to investigate. (If you wish to, instead of putting `set -x` at the top of your script, you could also run `ksh -x yourscript` with the same effect).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I used both ```set -x``` and an inline ```eval %!tempout```.  Both displayed a literal "%!tempout".  So as you suggested, my answer appears to be that it is a literal file name.

Comment: In C shells, the bang `!` is used with the history mechanism in interactive shells (and maybe percent `%` is used like that too). I'm not sure that history works with non-interactive shells. Normally, in Korn shell, `$!` means the PID of the last command run in background (using `&`) — and `$!tempout` will be interpreted as the value of `$!` followed immediately by the word `tempout`.  YMMV.

Comment: What is the version of ksh on the operating-system for which the legacy script was written, and what is that operating system version?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, yeah, I am familiar $ and ! and $!, but that is not my question.  Though I recognize the potential for some insight there, so thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a result of investigation based on @CharlesDuffy's comment, the answer appears to be that "%!tempout" is a literal file name.  In this case it is a file with postscript content, so perhaps the "%!" prefix is providing a format cue to whatever is consuming the file.